# why i am getting `gyp` failed with exit code: 1 errror on running npm install cammand

Tags: node.js, web-services, npm, npm-install, npm-package

``I am trying to run npm install and got that error node version - 14.16.1 npm version 6.14.12

```
got error :- 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit        (/home/ad.rapidops.com/ritika.jain/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-91-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/ad.rapidops.com/ritika.jain/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node" "/home/ad.rapidops.com/ritika.jain/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ad.rapidops.com/ritika.jain/Documents/frfr/dd-sm-import/node_modules/java
gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2        
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! java@0.12.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.12.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

trying to run npm install . this is package.json 
          }`

    i was trying to run npm install but it is not working initially i was getting not found make errror after that i have run one command that is ---sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

-- after that now i am getting this error .

```
    i was trying to run npm install but it is not working initially i was getting not found make errror after that i have run one command that is ---sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

-- after that now i am getting this error .

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm`?

If you still get this error, delete the node_module folder and .lock file first .

Comment: getting same error on running this cammand

Comment: Windows does not require sudo

Comment: delete node_module folder and package-lock.json . then `npm cache clean --force` , Try the `npm install --unsafe-perm` again

Comment: still got same error. i don't have java jbdc installed do i need to install it . i don't know if because of that i am getting this error . ?